# SQL Query: Binary Fields on Dates for Time Series

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, time-series

I have a table that looks like the following:

```
ID  |  Date
1   |  2010-01-01
2   |  2010-02-01
3   |  2010-02-15
2   |  2010-02-15
4   |  2010-03-01
```

I am having trouble creating a table with the IDs as rows, and Time periods as columns.  For a given time period, I would like to place a 1 if that ID has an associated date in that period, and a 0 if not.

So the output might look like:

```
ID  |  Jan-10  |  Feb-10  |  Mar-10
1   |  1       |  0       |  0
2   |  0       |  1       |  0
3   |  0       |  1       |  0
4   |  0       |  0       |  1
```

What is the best way to accomplish this?

I have created a new table containing all distinct IDs from the table above in anticipation of a join---but I'm not sure how to handle the 1/0s.

Comment: Is there a defined set of months, or do you need the number of columns to vary? Also - What RDMBS are you using?

Comment: Defined set of months, consistent across all IDs.  They will ultimately be labelled T1, T2, etc.  MS SQL Server 2005.

Comment: How is T1 defined? Is that definition consistent? How many Tx columns will there be?

Comment: If we can solve for the example here, with 3 time periods": 1/1/2010 >/ T1 > 2/1/2010 >/ T2 > 3/1/2010 >/ T3 > 4/1/2010. I believe can extrapolate for my needs.

Comment: (There will, however, be a couple hundred time periods.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a simple `group by` and conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
       max(case when month(t.date) = 1 and year(t.date) = 2010 then 1 else 0 end) as "Jan-10",
       max(case when month(t.date) = 2 and year(t.date) = 2010 then 1 else 0 end) as "Feb-10",
       max(case when month(t.date) = 3 and year(t.date) = 2010 then 1 else 0 end) as "Mar-10"
from "table" t
group by id;
```

Because you have so many time periods, I would generate the code for the column using formulas in Excel (or your favorite spreadsheet).